# How to find the most common text in a column, after using a formula to filter mutiple variables/columns in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, function, filter, mode

I want to find the most common word used in one column, after filtering two separate columns using a function, blank cells are present. The attached picture should make it easier to understand what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: Show your code and post data in OP not link to picture.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$7)-1/(AGGREGATE(14,6,COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$7,$C$2:$C$7,$B$2:$B$7,F2,$A$2:$A$7,E2),1)=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$7,$C$2:$C$7,$B$2:$B$7,F2,$A$2:$A$7,E2)),1))
```

[image]

To deal with the false positives:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$7=E2)*($B$2:$B$7=F2)*(AGGREGATE(14,6,COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$7,$C$2:$C$7,$B$2:$B$7,F2,$A$2:$A$7,E2),1)=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$7,$C$2:$C$7,$B$2:$B$7,F2,$A$2:$A$7,E2)),),0)),"")
```

This is a similar but different formula, it will throw an error if no match is found.  The IFERROR puts `""` when the formula returns the error.

Comment: Very cool! This pretty much does what I need it to, except for if a combination does not exist in the system, it will default to whatever the very top row is. It would be best to have it come up blank.